# How to remove unused files from directories

Tags: 6

I want to remove/delete files from site directories (e.g. `/sites/default/files/*`) that are not used in site. There are thousands of files that causing fillup size. Any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 8):

I found this post https://drupal.org/node/733258... may help...

The main purpose talked in this issue is about removing the images which doesn't have any use directly from database via SQL queries.

[Audit files module](http://drupal.org/project/auditfiles) is suggested as a good start (because doesn't delete files) to find files which are unused.

This code snippet is one of the suggested solution from the issue :

```
<?php
//db_query to find all files not attached to a node:
$result = db_query("SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM file_usage WHERE file_managed.fid = file_usage.fid) ");

//Delete file & database entry
for ($i = 1; $i <= $result->rowCount(); $i++) {
  $record = $result->fetchObject();
  $file = file_load($record->fid);
  if ($file != NULL) {
    file_delete($file);
  } }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way of searching the unused files is running the following query:

```
SELECT fm.*
FROM file_managed AS fm
LEFT OUTER JOIN file_usage AS fu ON (fm.fid = fu.fid)
LEFT OUTER JOIN node AS n ON (fu.id = n.nid)
WHERE fu.type = 'node' AND n.nid IS NULL
```

This query would return all the files that are not associated with any node.

Also, in order to avoid landing up in such situations its better to add a file_usage_add() to every file. This will enable the system to know that the file is being used. Appending a file_usage_delete() does a cron type job of removing unused files from the system.

Comment: This query will not return any unmanaged files.

Comment: The query seems identical to the one here https://www.drupal.org/node/733258#comment-5582764 that was posted 4 months earlier in the post which @jramby linked to.  If you look at that thread, there are some follow up comments which could be useful.

Comment: The file_usage table has a 'type' column that can be for example 'taxonomy_term' (perhaps an image field was added to a taxonomy) or 'file' (for IMCE). This query will not scan these other types.

Answer (score 1):

There is a sandbox project called [File Delete](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/osopolar/2470465), which provides the drush command `drush file-delete-unused --all` to delete all files reported in file_managed which aren't in file_usage. It deletes the file itself and the database-entry.

Comment: The drush command 'file-delete-unused' could not be found.  Run      [error]
`drush cache-clear drush` to clear the commandfile cache if you have
installed new extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You could either remove it manually or could go through https://drupal.org/node/733258 which would help you remove unwanted images.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example of removing unused gmap_markers files using drush:

```
drush sqlq "SELECT fid FROM file_managed WHERE status = 1 AND filename LIKE 'gmap_markers%'" | xargs -L1 -I% drush -v eval "file_delete(file_load(%));"
```

You can see all the Drupal files by:

```
drush sqlq "SELECT fid, filename, uri FROM file_managed WHERE status = 1"
```

To see if any specific file is not used, I'd suggest to scan for each of these files in the filesystem and database by the following example commands:

```
grep -R "my_file.jpg" /Drupal/webroot
drush --ordered-dump sql-dump | grep "my_file.jpg"
```

Once the file doesn't exists anywhere else apart of standard file_managed, etc. then I think it can be removed safely.